# Implementing conditional segue with custom delegate

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, delegates, storyboard

I am using storyboard. It has a login VC , which on success pushes to another VC. When the user enters the credentials and clicked on login button then it hits the server. I have implemented all the logic that contains hitting with server in a separate class which has delegate. When we get response then the control goes to the delegate method implemented in login VC. In the delegate method if status is success then only the login VC must be pushed in to another VC.

In Login VC

```
- (BOOL)shouldPerformSegueWithIdentifier:(NSString *)identifier sender:(id)sender
{
   Util *util = [[Util alloc]init];
   util.delegate = self;

   NSMutableDictionary *request = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];
   [request setValue:uname.text forKey:@“username”];
   [request setValue:pwd.text forKey:@“password”];
   [util body:request];
}
```

when server returns response it comes to the delegate method implemented in Login VC

```
- (void)response:(NSDictionary *)response
{
    //here i am going to check the status if it is success i will go to new VC else in same VC 
}
```

here i am unable to go to another VC since i am not in the shouldPerformSegueWithIdentifier: method.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you call

```
 [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"customerView" sender:self];
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're probably triggering your segue when the login button is tapped. You can't do this if you need to wait for a response from your web service. Instead, try connecting your button to a method when sends off your login request. When you receive your response, you can check if the user's login is valid, and **then** perform your segue programmatically:

```
- (void)response:(NSDictionary *)response
{
    if (something) // check if response is valid
    {
        [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"YourSegueIdentifier" sender:self];
    }
    else
    {
        // show error
    }
}
```

This way, you won't need to implement `shouldPerformSegueWithIdentifier:sender:` at all.